# Is it possible to plot a shape, on the chart candle, using an indicator script, like found for a 'strategy' scripts?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, candlesticks

I would like to know the exact entry and exit prices for the 'alertconditions' I know this can be done for a 'strategy script, but I can't get it to work for an 'indicator'.

the code below doesn't work.

```
plotshape(entry, title='Long Enter', color=color.new(#2d9331, 0), style=shape.cross, location=location.absolute, size=size.small, xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=entry_price, offset=0)
```

> Error: Cannot use 'plotshape' in local scope

Answer (score 0):

You have the error because you try to use plotshape inside a conditional block.

Use plotshape outside your conditional loop and use this condition inside the plotshape fonction on the color variable :

```
color = MyCondition ? color.new(#2d9331, 0) : na
```

if MyCondition is true, your plotshape will draw, else the color will be na and nothing will be drawn.

You should modify your code like this :

```
if MyCondition
    // your code

plotshape(entry, title='Long Enter', color = MyCondition ? color.new(#2d9331, 0) : na, style=shape.cross, location=location.absolute, size=size.small, xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=entry_price, offset=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I still can't get it to work. I get errors for the xloc and yloc

Comment: @Kansari do you still have this error 'Error: Cannot use 'plotshape' in local scope' ?

Comment: Yes I do. I cant get a 'plotshape' to plot on the actual price, it's either above or below bar. So for now, I'm using 'plot'. Not ideal, as it plots a line on the entry price, but continues plotting and till the next entry price.

Comment: plotshape(almaBUY, title='Enter bar', color=color.new(#2d9331, 0), style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, display=display.all)                                                                                  
                                                                                                                   
plot(entry_price, title='Enter Price', color=color.new(#2d9331, 0), style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2, editable = true)

Comment: @Kansari please try to modify plot with your condition on the color, as in my answer.

Comment: My coding skills are limited. Could you send me a link to a script with a similar plotshape? I have not come across one in the TV community.

Comment: @Kansari edit your question and paste your entire code. Without it , it is hard to help you.